# Angular - building a "public" function (newbie)

Tags: function, angularjs

I'm After several days learning angularJS through converting my standart JS app to a ng one.
I was wondering about this simple scenario:

I have a global function called fb_connect(), 
it can be used from any page (or any controller if you like) to make a facebook-based login.
This function makes a simple http call and receives a JSON object contain data to move on (display a pop up, login, etc...)

I read that I can define a Factory or a Service for my app and use it in any controller, which works fine.
So, I created a fb_connect factory function.
The problem is that now, in every page (every controller), I have to define that **fb_connect** in the constructor of every controller - for example :

```
function welcome($scope,fb_connect){});
```

What is the proper way to do this kind of actions using Angular without having to define these functions each and every time in every controller?

Thanks

Comment: If anyone has answered your question you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two options are:

- Declare the function on the `$rootScope`
- Inject it as a service

My advice is to go with making it a service. The whole purpose of services is explained in the Angular.js docs, just like this quote:

> Angular services are singletons that carry out specific tasks common to web apps... To use an Angular service, you identify it as a dependency for the dependent (a controller, or another service) that depends on the service.

As you mentioned in your question, you'd prefer to not define the service in every controller you wish to use it in. With `$rootScope` you'll be injecting that also in every controller. So really it's a question of which you prefer, although to answer your question, the proper way of using a factory or service is to inject it into the controller you wish to use it in.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up factories and services is all part of the *dependency injection* system of Angular. Using that system is great when you need to create things that depend on other injected things. It's a big tree of dependencies. It's also nice for creating singletons, such that everywhere in your code end up using the same instance of some object.

It sounds to me like neither of these benefits apply in your case. I'd suggest just not using Angular's DI for it. You have some function defined globally, just call it directly and skip the DI. There's nothing wrong with that.

Of course you say it makes an Ajax call, so doesn't depend on the Angular $http service?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put it in the $rootScope

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, fb_connect){
  $rootScope.welcome = function(){

  };
});
```